# Granule compression in cluster environment

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, minify, yui-compressor

I am using granule compression for compressing js and css and it works well in cluster environment too until i encounter an issue which has put me into thinking how granule works!!

Before i tell the problem , here are some of the queries i have

1.Granule generates "id" dynamically for js and css(`www.domain.com/contentPath?id=some random digis`).Is this id generation with respect to different browser or id remain constant when  app server is started?

**Problem insight:**

Actually caching of this is done by third party .i.e before user request hits our app server, js/css is cached by thirdy party and original url request is forward to app server which results in 404 error for js and css.

if we exclude third party from intercepting request,everything works fine.
Please provide me with necessary information.

Thank you

Note: app servers are clustered.

Comment: Does your caching service include the id query parameter in its  cache key?

Comment: Yes it apart of caching service.But why is third party service not able to cache?